# How to configure Visual Studio 2012 to use Beyond Compare 3

Tags: svn, visual-studio-2012, beyondcompare3

I would like to configure Visual Studio 2012 to open Beyond Compare by default as the diff tool. How can I do this?

I can't find an appropriate solution from http://www.scootersoftware.com/support.php?zz=kb_vcs#svn

*Note: The same SO question about VS 2010 is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4466238/how-to-configure-visual-studio-2010-to-use-beyond-compare) but 2012 differs.*

Comment: In what way does 2012 differ for you? When I looked in the configuration dialog the options looked the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The VS 2010 instructions work in VS 2012:
[How to configure Visual Studio to use Beyond Compare](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4466238/how-to-configure-visual-studio-2010-to-use-beyond-compare)

[image: User tools configuration dialog in VS2012]

Comment: NOTE -- it's important to say BComp.exe and not BCompare.exe.  I got a file not found on the server's copy when I used BCompare.exe

Answer (score 1):

In Visual Studio 2008 + , go to the

> ```
> Tools menu -->  select Options
> ```

[image]

> In Options Window --> expand Source Control --> Select Subversion User
>   Tools --> Select Beyond Compare

and click OK button..

Comment: This doesn't work when you use `Microsoft Git Provider` as your Source Control. `EDIT:` This does work for SVN and answers OP's questions, just wanted to add in for future readers as I didn't see SVN specifically in the OP's question, but noticed it later as a tag.

Answer (score 0):

Configure SVN to use BC, if you can't find old settings in new interface