# where are the missing settings in Tools=>options?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I'm trying to integrate Beyond Compare with VS.net 2010 Ultimate,  I found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4466238/how-to-configure-visual-studio-to-use-beyond-compare), but my Tools =>Options dialog has almost nothing in it.  For example, there are no "Project and Solutions" nor Source Control nodes.  I assume I'm missing something basic, so where are the other option nodes?

This is what I see:

[image: This is my screen shot]

Comment: Bottom left of that window ...

Comment: ahhh, needed another cup of coffee

Answer (score 1):

Click "Show all settings" checkbox. It will solve issue.