# How to configure Visual Studio (TFS) to use BeyondCompare3 (broken for xml files)

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs, beyondcompare3

I used the [instructions on the BeyondCompare website](http://www.scootersoftware.com/support.php?zz=kb_vcs#tfs) (also referenced in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4466238/how-to-configure-visual-studio-to-use-beyond-compare)) to configure VS2010 (TFS) to compare source control using Beyond Compare. This approach appears to be broken. The file in the left-hand view (from the server) does not appear at all in BC3, and a `Conversion Error` is reported.

Upon further inspection, I noticed that the filename generated by Visual Studio when serving up the file from the source control (i.e., the previous revision) looks like this: `filename.xml;C1956`. There is a *semicolon* in the filename, as a delimiter between the original filename and the rev number. This is confusing BC3. To confirm this, I took the served-up version of the file (which gets stored temporarily in `\AppData\Local\Temp\TFSTemp\`), and renamed it, removing the semicolon. BC3 loaded it just fine. But when I put the semicolon back in, the `Conversion Error` returned.

**UPDATE:** Upon further testing, I realize this is only an issue with `XML` files. If I rename the file with a different extension, BC3 loads it just fine.

Has anybody discovered a workaround for this?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out (after contacting the very efficient ScooterSoftware support desk) the problem was with the XML formatting plugins. In BC3, under Tools -> File Formats, I disabled (unchecked) the following formatters:
* XML Tidied
* XML Tidied with Attributes Sorted
The semicolon-file then displayed just fine. These formatters use the freeware converter, HtmlTidy, from http://tidy.sourceforge.net. I haven't determined whether a newer version of this plugin might help. For now I've just turned them off (which works for this situation because the visual studio xml is already "tidy".)