# How to easily copy old version line difference to new version?

Tags: visual-studio, diff

I've just moved to MSVS2013 from MSVS2010.  On 2010, I was able to use my own diff util.  It allowed me to skip from one change to the next and if the entire change is not wanted, I could back it out with a single keystroke.

Under 2013, I can't seem to select my own diff util, nor can I just backout a change group with a single keystroke.

Is there a way of changing the diff util?  Or is there a way of backing out a change group with a single keystroke?

I just ran an automated code modifier and I have a lot of files to go through.  I don't want to have stop my searching using F8/Shift-F8 just to pick up my mouse to copy and paste each change group that I don't want. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure about the rest of your question, but you can change the diff tool in:
 Tools->Options->Source Control->Visual Studio Team Foundation Server->Configure User Tools.

Heres a post regarding setting up Beyond Compare with some screenshots:
[How to configure Visual Studio to use Beyond Compare](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4466238/how-to-configure-visual-studio-to-use-beyond-compare)

Comment: Yeah, I finally found it.  It was the same as in 2010, which is strange since I thought I looked there already.  However, I would have liked it if the MSVS2013 built in diff tool had the ability to, upon going to a change group, back out that change with a keystroke like other diff utils. :(