# Configure Beyond Compare in Visual Studio for config Preview Transform

Tags: visual-studio, web-config, beyondcompare3

I've configured Beyond Compare in Visual Studio 2013 as described in [How to configure Visual Studio to use Beyond Compare](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4466238/how-to-configure-visual-studio-to-use-beyond-compare/4466372#4466372)

Now I am working with a new web project and added web.config transformation files.

When I try to perform a «Preview Transform» I get the error message «Parameter count mismatch».

I deleted the Compare operation and then the preview works and is opened with the default compare view of Visual Studio.

Therefore I suppose there is something wrong with the Arguments %1 %2 /title1=%6 /title2=%7

I tried already with just %1 %2 but to no avail.

So the question is: does anybody know which arguments have to been set so that the preview works with Beyond Compare as well?

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to specify the extensions I wanted to use BCompare for.

In other words, don't put .* as the extension.

For me, I work in mostly c++ and c#, so I included '.c,.cs,.cpp,.h,.txt, .log'

Now, when I preview transform, VS uses it's own diffing tool -- and beyondCompare for everything else I regularly compare.

Comment: After all I chose this approach as well.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, under Tools/Options using Beyond Compare 4.

[image: Visual Studio 2013 settings]