# Error - Parameter Count Mismatch

Tags: slowcheetah

I'm looking to use `SlowCheetah` to do build time transforms. I'm running Visual Studio 2013 update 1.

My transform could be the world's simplest; in `web.Debug.config` I have

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
    <appSettings>
       <add key="test" value="test"  xdt:Transform="Insert"/>
    </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

When I try to preview transform I get the following error:

> [image: Slow Cheetah Parameter Count Mismatch]

Does anyone have any ideas? Are there any sort of logs or output I can look at?

Comment: As per http://stackoverflow.com/q/22554145, there is a chance this may be due to an external merge/diff tool.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect this might be a bug in VS 2013 update 1. I've got the same version of Visual Studio and came across the same issue today. 
I've got the same error when trying to preview transforms of existing projects (created in VS 2012) and the preview used to work.