# Visual studio Source Control tab is missing tabs

Tags: visual-studio-2015, beyondcompare4

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0RzI7.png)

from the options tab in tools tab, the source control tab should has also "visual studio team foundation server" for editing the diff/merge tools as this solution for the beyond compare problem:
[How to configure Visual Studio to use Beyond Compare](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4466238/how-to-configure-visual-studio-to-use-beyond-compare)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **Source Control > Plug-in Selection**, if you change the **Current source control plug-in** dropdown from **Git** to **Visual Studio Team Foundation Server**, it will add the **Source Control > Visual Studio Team Foundation Server** section so you can configure User Tools.

[image: Visual Studio 2015 - Options - Source Control]