# How do I set WinMerge as the merge tool in Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, winmerge

I tried editing my C:\ProgramData\Git\config file, but that had no effect. I used to have WinMerge configured as my merge tool in Visual Studio, but I switched to the new built-in tool and didn't like it and now I can't get my WinMerge back! Help!

Here's what I added to the config file:

```
[merge]
    tool = winmerge
[mergetool "winmerge"]
    cmd = \"C:\\Program Files\\WinMerge\\WinMergeU.exe\" \"$REMOTE\" \"$LOCAL\" \"$BASE\" \"$MERGED\"
```

Is there another config file, say, one for my user profile, overriding this global file?

Comment: Better to do it via the GUI. Check eg here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4466372/89706

Answer (score 0):

Aha! There was another config file. It was located at C:\Users(me).gitconfig.