# How to configure Visual Studio to use Beyond Compare on Mac?

Tags: macos, visual-studio, beyondcompare

There's a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4466238/16004728), but all the provided answers seem to be for Windows.

Is there any way to do this on Mac?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like Visual Studio 2019 for Mac supports external diff tools.

On Windows, Visual Studio will use Beyond Compare for diff and merge if it's defined in .gitconfig.

On Mac, you'll need to diff outside of Visual Studio to open a comparison in Beyond Compare.

To configure Beyond Compare on Mac as the git diff tool:

1. In Beyond Compare, select **Beyond Compare > Install Command Line Tools** from the menu.
2. In a Terminal, run `git config --global diff.tool bc`.
3. To launch a diff, run `git difftool file.ext`.

Reference: https://www.scootersoftware.com/support.php?zz=kb_vcs_osx#git